# Page refresh returns 404 error on deployed vuejs vue-router apllication

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

The homepage/base url of the app can be refreshed with no issues. but other pages return 404 on page refresh. Please are there any work around for this?

Here is a screenshot of the 404.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc8xD.png

Comment: Can you please show the <template> and <script> of the component/page where the 404 occurs?

Comment: It happens to all pages thats not the base url... I dont think it has anything to do with code, I think it has to do with the virtual url vue-router history mode sets in the browser url bar. They're not real so when the page refreshes, http server tries to load the url and fails.. There must be an all-server acceptable work around for this.

Answer (score 5):

It happens because Vue routing is only on the frontend side. So when you refresh the page it goes backend server. And it checks for any files to satisfy the request.

To solve this issue. You have to tell your apache webserver to handle it for your front end Vue app.

Comment: How do i do that please...?

Comment: Check this link https://sanakil.blogspot.com/2021/03/deploy-vue-js-app-in-subfolder.html . It will help you. I have written it for the subfolder but you can use it with the base URL(/) too. You just have to set up an apache configuration.

Comment: Thanks. It doesnt bring an error message now. It just shows blank.

Comment: @Jacky001 have you resolve the issue? I'm hosting my web now and getting the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me:

In   */etc/apache2/sites-available/"yourAppDomain".conf*   add to the end:

> **FallbackResource /index.html**
> `</VirtualHost>`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It doesnt work even after refreshing apache server. However error text is not displaying. It just blank and doesnt redirect.

Comment: I believe this can guide you to the solution: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations

Answer (score 0):

Page refresh returns 404 error VueJs (mode:history) with Laravel:

The solution that worked for **Laravel**:

Assuming your entry point is the index method, you just need to add this route at the bottom of your routes/web.php file.

```
Route::get('{any}', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->where('any','.*');
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution which works for me and router works too :)

IIS setup rewrite rule:

```html
<rule name="MY SPA APP REWRITE RULE" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="myAppBaseURL/(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/myAppBaseURL?rewriteURL={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

And then in the main App.vue add this

```js
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
const router = useRouter()

if(new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('rewriteURL')){
  router.push(new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('rewriteURL'))
}
```